# Path.join throws exception when given private variable as argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

I'm experimenting with Electron and I was trying to load an html file, and I store the path to that file in a private variable. Refer to code below.

However Path.join fails with this error:

[image: undefined argument error.]

BUT if I pass a string literal with the same value it works.

Non-working code:

```js
import * as Electron from 'electron'
import * as Path from 'path'
import { Option, Some, None } from './option'

export default class Main
{
    private indexFilePath = 'index.html'
    private app: Electron.App
    private browserWindow: Option<Electron.BrowserWindow>

    constructor (app: Electron.App)
    {
        this.app = app
        this.browserWindow = new None()
        this.app.on('ready', this.onReady)
    }

    private onReady(): void
    {
        this.browserWindow = new Some(new Electron.BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        }))
        this.browserWindow.unwrap().loadFile(Path.join(__dirname, this.indexFilePath))
    }
}
```

Working code:

```js
import * as Electron from 'electron'
import * as Path from 'path'
import { Option, Some, None } from './option'

export default class Main
{
    private app: Electron.App
    private browserWindow: Option<Electron.BrowserWindow>

    constructor (app: Electron.App)
    {
        this.app = app
        this.browserWindow = new None()
        this.app.on('ready', this.onReady)
    }

    private onReady(): void
    {
        this.browserWindow = new Some(new Electron.BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        }))
        this.browserWindow.unwrap().loadFile(Path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
    }
}
```

This doesn't make any sense to me and just increases my frustration with anything that has javascript in it. It feels like a whacky supersonic plane that could obliterate itself at any moment...

I did check if it was some weird typescript compilation error but no, doesn't matter which javascript version I choose the result is the same. Compiled code looks like this, I see nothing wrong with it either:

```js
class Main {
    constructor(app) {
        this.indexFilePath = 'index.html';
        this.app = app;
        this.browserWindow = new option_1.None();
        this.app.on('ready', this.onReady);
    }
    onReady() {
        this.browserWindow = new option_1.Some(new Electron.BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        }));
        this.browserWindow.unwrap().loadFile(Path.join(__dirname, this.indexFilePath));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: That's an unambiguously clear error? Step 1 would be console logging `__dirname` and `this.indexFilePath` in your non-working code: what's actually in them?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans fair point but it wouldn't have gotten me anywhere as I didn't understand WHY it was undefined. With your answer it's pretty clear, cheers

Comment: No, but it would have given you a better question to ask, which much smaller code, because it'd have been a variation of "I have a class with a private field, but when I console log it, it shows as undefined. What's going on". Which would have probably also let you go "hang on, what if I search for that, instead".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic scoping error: just because you're pulling `ready` from `this`, does not mean that `this.ready` has any defined scope, it's just a bare function.

So, when you call `this.app.on('ready', this.onReady)`, you are not telling JS to preserve the meaning of the `this` keyword at the time of declaration. Instead, any use of `this` that JS encounters once it runs your function will be "whatever the scope is at the time of *execution*", and when the event handling code triggers, that will be the global scope instead of your class instance.

Pretty simple solution: this is what we invented arrow functions for.

```
this.app.on('ready', () => this.onReady())
```

Done, when this function gets executed, its `this` is still the same as it was at declare time.

Comment: Hah, it does make sense! I'm pretty new to Javascript, I'm trying to wrap my head around it still most of the time. Thanks.

Comment: reading up on how JS handles scoping early in on your journey into JS is going to save _so much time_ later on =)